# Avoid graph to load old and new data adjacent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwBQG.png)

```
this.state.loading ? "loading..." : Chart items = {this.state.item} />
```

This how I render the component items as prop.

`Chart` component `return`

```
Line id={key} redraw = {true} data={state} options={{responsive: true }} />
```

`key` unique number value typecasted as a `string`
state is the object with all the labels, data value, and design values.

I just want to `Load` a single `graph` at a time, instead of looping one `graph adjacent` to each other every time new data is fetched, without using map function.